# javascript storing global variables in DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly large script that contains about 60 global variables. I'm thinking about using the namespace pattern to encapsulate my script and have only one global variable that references one object.

Even though this pattern is considered best practice, I'm also thinking about an alternative: storing the global variables inside the DOM, in hidden divs, and accessing them with `$('#MyGlobalVar1').text()`. Is this a good idea or not?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Don't store them in the dom.  It's hard for me to imagine a cleanly-architectred script that requires 60 globals. Rather than just using the namespace pattern to scope them, you mnight also consider refactoring to separate these variables from each other. Break it down into functions which each maintain their own private globals. I guess it's *possible* that you need 60 globals but it would be surprising to me.

Comment: @Cheeso: the script is about 11,000 lines long. It's a single page HTML5 application. Hence my 60 globals.

Comment: The length of the script should not influence the number of global  symbols than must be exported.

Comment: @Cheeso: well anyway, everything will be namespaced in one global object so in the end, there'll just be one global variable.

Comment: I understand that, but you've still got 60 vars in a single (hidden) scope, and to me, that screams "Refactor me!"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not a good idea.

It pollutes the DOM with non-semantic data, and is less efficient as well. That's even *worse* than polluting the global JS namespace, and worse still, it only allows you to store strings.

Comment: plus, performance would be horrible querying the DOM for every value.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant by "less efficient."

Comment: less efficient could also be requiring a `JSON.stringify(val)` every time you want to set a value in the DOM. I vomited a little.

Comment: You could always just attach regular JavaScript properties to the hidden div object, rather than setting and parsing its state via its text content, but it's still not great for the other reasons mentioned. The global namespace is so polluted in JavaScript anyway it probably won't make much of a difference to add one global to it. Besides if you're essentially namespacing things and following good conventions, that's about as good as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

Even if I would recommend you to use a *namespace object* to hold and reference your data, you can simply put an outer self-invoking function around your code to prevent clobbering the global object.

So you go from

```
var global1 = true,
    global2 = true;
```

into

```
(function() {
    var global1 = true,
        global2 = true;

    // rest of all app logic
}());
```

Beyond that, since you're using jQuery you also might to use jQuerys [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/data/) method. It's designed to reference data for a specific node, but it's internally stored into an ECMAscript object also.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: why is that? I don't get what my answer has to do with CoffeeScript (I actually never used it)

Comment: This would work, unless frenchie is setting global variables as `window.variable`.  This is why it's important to avoid globals in the first place.